# C++ How to dynamically create a 2D vector

Tags: c++, xcode, vector, 2d-vector

I'm trying to create an n x n vector that I can later `cout` as a table/matrix. Xcode points to the `=` in the `for` loop and tells me `No viable overloaded '='`. I don't know what that means or how to fix it.

```
int n=5;
vector< vector<int> > row(n);
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   row[i] = new vector<int> column(n);
}
```

Also tried this, but Xcode didn't like it either and this time pointed to `column` and said `Expected ')'` :

```
int n=5;
vector< vector<int> > row;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   row.push_back(new vector<int> column(n));
}
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the way I'm declaring the new vector `column` inside the `for` loop. Any help/advice is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
int n = 5;
std::vector< std::vector<int> > row(n);
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   row[i].push_back( std::vector<int>(n) );
}
```

or

```
int n = 5;
std::vector< std::vector<int> > row(n, std::vector<int>( n ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution is to use the relevant [constructor of `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), initializing it to `n` elements each having the value of `val` - no loops necessary.

```
std::vector<T> (n, val);
```

---

Having your original snippet we would end up with the following, which will initialize row to have `n` *std::vector*s, each of which having `n` elements.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > row (n, std::vector<int> (n));
```

Answer (score 0):

When the constructor of `row` is called, all elements are initialized too. 
I think this code does what you're looking to do:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    row[i].resize(n);
}
```

Now all elements of row will be of size `n`.